# Close-Enough TSP implementation

Tags: traveling-salesman

I'm looking for a solution to a Close-Enough Traveling Salesman Problem (CETSP) where I have a set of nodes that I need to visit all within a certain distance of optimally. I've found a couple of sources for some approaches towards this TSP variant but was unable to find a solver or a algorithm that I could easily use.

Do you have any suggestions for how I can go about getting a solution to my CETSP problem, whether it be running an implementation of it myself or using an existing solver.

Comment: Existing solvers include [OptaPlanner](http://www.optaplanner.org/), Coin-or, LocalSolver, concorde, ...

Comment: IIRC, stackoverflow doesn't like questions that ask for a technology recommendation though...

Answer (score 0):

You can try using UFFLP. They have an example where you can find the correct coordinates the salesman is supposed to pass given a predetermined sequence. So you can generate thousands of sequences and choose the best one (just a simple heuristic).

Have a look at http://www.gapso.com.br/en/ufflp-en/

You will find useful information.